# Tool for automatic GUI testing of Gupta Windows applications?

Tags: automated-testing, gui

> I'm searching for (a) tool(s) to write and execute automatic GUI testing of Windows 7 applications written with [Gupta Team Developer](http://www.guptatechnologies.com/Products/App_Dev/TeamDeveloper/).

We got "QTP" here but its main problem is that it can't identify GUIs and elements constantly, so that written tests have to be rewritten every time the version changes as the GUI gets new Window IDs.

> Does anyone know other tools for this? Gupta application MUST be supported!

Comment: Do your GUI elements have any other attributes that you can use to identify them? If the Windows IDs are changeable, there should be something else you can grab - field name or possibly a portion of the field name. You should be able to do that with QTP.

Comment: Not really that's the problem. I could imagine that the missing IDs are a problem of developement, but how to get the time of devs to change it by the managers. But a workmate said QTP isn't able to be used for Gupta at all and so even if we had the IDs it wouldn't work.

Comment: After doing further digging into it and trying out some other tool the problem with QTP is that it doesn't support Gupta applications by default. HP wrote some dlls for my company several years ago to run QTP with those days Gupta version. But at least since Gupta 6.2 several elements are not supported (like `menu` are now `ProfUIS-ControlBar`). As we are bound to QTP due restrictions (as I know now) I think my question is nearly unable to be answered in a way I could accept an answer. I'm sorry for that, but I hope other tester find something helpful in this thread. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 2):

[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) with [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/) might be a good fit for you. Sikuli uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question I think you are looking for a tool to automate windows application or desktop applications. 
I suggest you take a look a Autoit.

Autoit works for all the windows or the desktop based application.

You can even integrate it with selenium webdrivers to perform combined web and desktop based automation.

Visit : https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: I tried autoit for some time and it can identify at least more elements than QTP acutally can, but not all, which may be caused by the new gupta version. For see info my comment at my question.

Comment: Have you tried simulating mouse clicks on the software using autoit. If your application has not got any ID then you can send the XY coordinates of the button and get the mouse to click then. Though this is not the preferred way but can act as a workaround when your application has missing IDs

Comment: Yeah I did and it works (even with QTP). But I (or we - to speak for the whol QS team) prefer a way to write the scripts once and only have to change them when explicit items changed. Up to that we prefer to work with unique IDs/Names what's not possible atm. Especially since Gupta 6.2 some classes have changed, like for `menu` so we would have to XY all menu entries. And for such big changes to the scripts we don't have the OK from "above" (as for automatic tests at all...). You can see this with looking at my response time for this thread